# Using a variable as a file name and writing to the file in bash

Tags: bash, file, variables, unix

So I am trying to write to a file and I want my file name to be the time when I opened it. I have something like this:

```
var=$(date +"%D-%H:%M:%S")
echo "I opened a file" > $var
cat $var
```

When I try to run this code, it gives me the error:

```
 NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY
```

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use quotes in your variable while using it:

```
var="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S")"
echo "I opened a file" > "$var"
cat "$var"
```

EDIT: Your problem is use of slash `/` in your date variable that makes shell thinks that it is a path rather than a file name. You will need to change your date format as I suggested above.

Comment: Also, if you're going to do this a lot, you may gain some efficiency by using `exec 3> "${var}"; ... echo "something" >&3`...  That'll save a lot of open/append/close cycles on your log file by only opening it once and then writing repeatedly to the appropriate file descriptor. Depending on your use case, though, it may not be necessary...

Answer (score 0):

That's because your redirect is to the file name ':' and the rest of the filename are being wordsplit into following parameters. [Use more quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting).

The other problem is that you cannot create a filename with slashes in it. Of course, that's a directory structure. You will need to replace the slashes with something else. You can do this by modifying the `date` command, but it's also easy to use [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), as I show below:

```
var=$(date +"%D-%H:%M:%S")
$ echo "$var"
03/12/14-15:20:46
$ echo 'data' > "${var//\//_}" # replace slashes with underscores
```

If you're just trying to create datestamped files, consider using the [epoch timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

```
var=$(date +%s)
echo "$somedata" > "$var"
```

It's easy for a machine to convert values to/from the epoch timestamp, and it's easier for you and most users to deal with a filename made up of a string of digits than a human-readable timestamp.

Comment: Can you elaborate more... I am not sure what you mean... Thanks